# Trouble passing vector<string> as function parameter C++

Tags: c++, vector, parameter-passing

So here is the code I'm working with. I would like to be able to pass all of the input into this function `new_flight` which there is currently no code for other then an empty declaration. I'm trying to pass tokens by reference but I've tried it with `*` `&` and just by value, and none seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void new_flight( vector<string> &tokens );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    vector<string> tokens;

    cout << "Reservations >> ";
    getline(cin, input);
    istringstream iss( input );
    copy(istream_iterator<string>( iss ),
         istream_iterator<string>(),
         back_inserter<vector<string> > ( tokens ));

    new_flight( tokens );
}
```

Here is what the compiler is telling me

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "new_flight(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccplPBEo.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

also if I comment out the line where I actually pass tokens to new_flight `new_flight( tokens )` it compiles fine.

Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Did you even implement the `new_flight` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to stub out a function you need to provide a function definition, not a function declaration:

```
void new_flight( vector<string> &tokens ) {
    // Not implemented
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting is not a compiler error, but a *linker* error, and it is due to the fact that your function `new_flight()` is not defined. But you seem to be aware of this fact. You cannot expect your program to work if you invoke a function that is not defined, so the linker refuses to create it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the function `new_flight`, but not defining it, so the linker can't link it.  Write the implementation (if only a stub one), and it will compile.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a declaration. You need a definition. What code is the compiler supposed to produce for this call? It has no code for the function. Your program cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

As other posts have pointed out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void new_flight( vector<string> &tokens );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   vector<string> tokens;

   cout << "Reservations >> ";
   getline(cin, input);
   istringstream iss( input );
   copy(istream_iterator<string>( iss ),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter<vector<string> > ( tokens ));

   new_flight( tokens );
}

void new_flight( vector<string> &tokens ) 
{

   // implementation
}
```

Because you're essentially defining the functionality after main, the compiler needs to know that the function exists hence we create a "prototype" `void new_flight( vector<string> &tokens );` which defines the function.